# Liquibase missing postgresql missing database driver

Tags: sql, postgresql, liquibase, sql-update

We recently made the transition from pure PostgreSQL development in bash to Liquibase updates and I am having a very hard time trying to get the application to even run.

Here is my configuration file (`liquibase.properties`)

```
####     _     _             _ _
##      | |   (_)           (_) |
##      | |    _  __ _ _   _ _| |__   __ _ ___  ___
##      | |   | |/ _` | | | | | '_ \ / _` / __|/ _ \
##      | |___| | (_| | |_| | | |_) | (_| \__ \  __/
##      \_____/_|\__, |\__,_|_|_.__/ \__,_|___/\___|
##                  | |
##                  |_|
##
##      The liquibase.properties file stores properties which do not change often,
##      such as database connection information. Properties stored here save time
##      and reduce risk of mistyped command line arguments.
##      Learn more: https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/config_properties.html
####
####
##   Note about relative and absolute paths:
##      The liquibase.properties file requires paths for some properties.
##      The classpath is the path/to/resources (ex. src/main/resources).
##      The changeLogFile path is relative to the classpath.
##      The url H2 example below is relative to 'pwd' resource.
####
# Enter the path for your changelog file.
changeLogFile=db/changelog/master.xml

#### Enter the Target database 'url' information  ####
#liquibase.command.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:5432/foo
liquibase.command.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/foo

# Enter the username for your Target database.
liquibase.command.username: my_username

# Enter the password for your Target database.
liquibase.command.password: my_password
```

And everytime I run it, it keeps complaining about some missing database driver

```
$ liquibase update
####################################################
##   _     _             _ _                      ##
##  | |   (_)           (_) |                     ##
##  | |    _  __ _ _   _ _| |__   __ _ ___  ___   ##
##  | |   | |/ _` | | | | | '_ \ / _` / __|/ _ \  ##
##  | |___| | (_| | |_| | | |_) | (_| \__ \  __/  ##
##  \_____/_|\__, |\__,_|_|_.__/ \__,_|___/\___|  ##
##              | |                               ##
##              |_|                               ##
##                                                ## 
##  Get documentation at docs.liquibase.com       ##
##  Get certified courses at learn.liquibase.com  ## 
##  Free schema change activity reports at        ##
##      https://hub.liquibase.com                 ##
##                                                ##
####################################################
Starting Liquibase at 21:31:35 (version 4.4.2 #39 built at 2021-07-22 18:11+0000)
Liquibase Version: 4.4.2
Liquibase Community 4.4.2 by Datical
Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: org.postgresql.Driver

For more information, please use the --log-level flag
```

And here is the full debug logs

```
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.hub.apiKey found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.filterLogMessages found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.resource] Adding path /home/leeoswald/Documents/foo-db/. to resourceAccessor liquibase.resource.FileSystemResourceAccessor
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.shouldRun aka should.run found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] Configuration liquibase.shouldRun is using the default value of true
####################################################
##   _     _             _ _                      ##
##  | |   (_)           (_) |                     ##
##  | |    _  __ _ _   _ _| |__   __ _ ___  ___   ##
##  | |   | |/ _` | | | | | '_ \ / _` / __|/ _ \  ##
##  | |___| | (_| | |_| | | |_) | (_| \__ \  __/  ##
##  \_____/_|\__, |\__,_|_|_.__/ \__,_|___/\___|  ##
##              | |                               ##
##              |_|                               ##
##                                                ## 
##  Get documentation at docs.liquibase.com       ##
##  Get certified courses at learn.liquibase.com  ## 
##  Free schema change activity reports at        ##
##      https://hub.liquibase.com                 ##
##                                                ##
####################################################
Starting Liquibase at 21:42:38 (version 4.4.2 #39 built at 2021-07-22 18:11+0000)
Liquibase Version: 4.4.2
Liquibase Community 4.4.2 by Datical
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.outputFile found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.command.update.changeExecListenerClass found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.command.changeExecListenerClass found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.command.update.changeExecListenerPropertiesFile found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.command.changeExecListenerPropertiesFile found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.command.update.changelogFile found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] Found 'liquibase.command.changelogFile' configuration of 'db/changelog/master.xml'
    file /home/leeoswald/Documents/foo-db/liquibase.properties 'changeLogFile' of 'db/changelog/master.xml'
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.command.update.contexts found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.command.contexts found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.command.update.defaultCatalogName found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.command.defaultCatalogName found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.command.update.defaultSchemaName found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.command.defaultSchemaName found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.command.update.driver found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.command.driver found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.command.update.driverPropertiesFile found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.command.driverPropertiesFile found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.command.update.labels found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.command.labels found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.command.update.password found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] Found 'liquibase.command.password' configuration of '*****'
    file /home/leeoswald/Documents/foo-db/liquibase.properties 'liquibase.command.password' of '*****'
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.command.update.url found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] Found 'liquibase.command.url' configuration of 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/foo'
    file /home/leeoswald/Documents/foo-db/liquibase.properties 'liquibase.command.url' of 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/foo'
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.command.update.username found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] Found 'liquibase.command.username' configuration of 'postgres'
    file /home/leeoswald/Documents/foo-db/liquibase.properties 'liquibase.command.username' of 'postgres'
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.command] Pipeline for command 'update: liquibase.command.core.UpdateCommandStep
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.propertyProviderClass found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.databaseClass found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.hub.url found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] Configuration liquibase.hub.url is using the default value of https://hub.liquibase.com
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.integration] Liquibase Hub URL:      https://hub.liquibase.com
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] No configuration value for liquibase.hub.mode found
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.configuration] Configuration liquibase.hub.mode is using the default value of ALL
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.integration] Liquibase Hub Mode:     ALL
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.CockroachDatabase
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.DB2Database
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.Db2zDatabase
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.DerbyDatabase
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.Firebird3Database
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.FirebirdDatabase
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.H2Database
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.HsqlDatabase
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.InformixDatabase
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.Ingres9Database
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.MSSQLDatabase
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.MariaDBDatabase
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.MockDatabase
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.MySQLDatabase
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.OracleDatabase
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.PostgresDatabase
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.SQLiteDatabase
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.SybaseASADatabase
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.SybaseDatabase
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.UnsupportedDatabase
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.database] Properties:
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.database] Key:'password' Value:'**********'
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] FINE [liquibase.database] Key:'user' Value:'postgres'
[2021-07-29 21:42:38] SEVERE [liquibase.integration] java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: org.postgresql.Driver
liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: org.postgresql.Driver
    at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:153)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandRunner.call(CommandRunner.java:45)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandRunner.call(CommandRunner.java:15)
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1953)
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$1300(CommandLine.java:145)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2352)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2346)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2311)
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2179)
    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2078)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.lambda$execute$1(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:318)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:175)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:151)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.execute(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:290)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.main(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:83)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: org.postgresql.Driver
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.run(Main.java:447)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.run(Main.java:225)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:175)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:151)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:225)
    at liquibase.command.AbstractCliWrapperCommandStep.run(AbstractCliWrapperCommandStep.java:32)
    at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:147)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: org.postgresql.Driver
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:125)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1523)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.lambda$run$0(Main.java:402)
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:166)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:175)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:165)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:144)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.run(Main.java:401)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: org.postgresql.Driver
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:217)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:176)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:141)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:90)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: org.postgresql.Driver
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.loadDriver(DatabaseFactory.java:272)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:201)
    ... 30 more

Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: org.postgresql.Driver

liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: org.postgresql.Driver
    at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:153)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandRunner.call(CommandRunner.java:45)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandRunner.call(CommandRunner.java:15)
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1953)
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$1300(CommandLine.java:145)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2352)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2346)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2311)
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2179)
    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2078)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.lambda$execute$1(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:318)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:175)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:151)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.execute(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:290)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.main(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:83)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: org.postgresql.Driver
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.run(Main.java:447)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.run(Main.java:225)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:175)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:151)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:225)
    at liquibase.command.AbstractCliWrapperCommandStep.run(AbstractCliWrapperCommandStep.java:32)
    at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:147)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: org.postgresql.Driver
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:125)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1523)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.lambda$run$0(Main.java:402)
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:166)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:175)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:165)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:144)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.run(Main.java:401)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: org.postgresql.Driver
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:217)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:176)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:141)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:90)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: org.postgresql.Driver
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.loadDriver(DatabaseFactory.java:272)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:201)
    ... 30 more
```

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Well, you didn't specify the location of the driver's jar file in the properties file or the command line. How do you expect liquibase to know where you put the driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you already copy the postgrest JDBC jar into liquidbase/lib ? https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/database-setup-tutorials/postgresql.html

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29973729)